# Azure Batch data science VM python packages missing

Tags: python, azure, azure-batch

I'm using the Linux DSVM image: `microsoft-dsvm linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu linuxdsvmubuntu`

My python code fails at first line `import pandas as pd` with a python error, module not found.

When i remote SSH into the node and run a `pip install pandas` it tells me it's already installed. Same goes for numpy etc.

I've tried to setup a start task with `/bin/bash -c "pip install pandas"` etc. but it fails with command `pip` not found.

Again when running from the SSH shell pip is on the PATH and there is no problem running it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The simple tutorials from microsoft works fine as they don't rely on any external packages. So I'm able to upload my python file and datasets etc. from blob storage onto the machine. And python runs ok. It's just like all the data science specific packages and pip is missing when the task is running, but its there when i SSH into the node.

Bonus question, is jupyter suppose to be running on port 8000?

Comment: You can try to create the task in the Azure portal with a Pool autouser, Admin for the user identity. Maybe your permission is not enough.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT Thank you will try that. I realised that when i SSH in i default to python 3.5 environment. But when launching the task using azure module from python on my client machine it gets run in python 2.7. But i'll try your suggestion.

Comment: You should also check if the node is a real one in your batch cluster.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT I'ev tried a manual task, aswell as setting the auto user from my python client code. But still getting `ImportError: No module named pandas` :(

Comment: I mean in the Azure portal. If you create the task through python, you should find the right way. Because I am not family with python. So I can just give the possible directory.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT It seems i get Permission Denied when i use the command line '/bin/bash -c "cd /anaconda/envs/py35;./bin/activate py35;...." Thats as a pool admin user? how else can i elevate my user? Should the admin user not have full rights?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT I'm a linux command line noob. I got it working i think with the following command line: '/bin/bash -c "source /anaconda/envs/py35/activate py35;....' Now my python program just fails due to some other file not found, but i think thats due to a change in the task's working directory.

Comment: I take the try and find that if you use different user you have different permission. You can use the command `whoami` to show the current user. Some commands need the root permission to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to install pip in your compute nodes.

```
bin/bash -c "sudo apt-get -y update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip && sudo pip3 install pandas;"
```

Provide this command as a startup task to the azure batch pool which will install pip and pandas in your virtual machines.

Same way put all the libraries that you want to install in a requirements.txt and give `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt` after installing pip.